# How to change the header of the details expand/collapse columns for the detail rows in kendo react?

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, header, customization

I need add the text "+/-" in the header of the collapse/expand column for details rows in kendo react. I also want to add and event so when the user clicks on that column, it expands or collapse all the rows. I've used [this](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/advanced-features/detail/) to create the details rows.

[This image shows better what i want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRWS3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

Telerik provided an answer for this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-abh1id?file=app/main.jsx

### Original:

I've debugged kendo-react library and it's not possible to make it happen. I've open a feature request for kendo React https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/1408002-change-header-detail-rows

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this code snippet it adds the grid lable and a onclick function. 
The part I haven't figured out is to toggle the expand/collapse. 
I also came across this property [expandField](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/api/GridProps/#toc-expandfield), but I do not know how to use it.

```
class DetailComponent extends GridDetailRow {
    render() {
        const dataItem = this.props.dataItem;
        return (
            <section>
                <p><strong>In Stock:</strong> {dataItem.UnitsInStock} units</p>
                <p><strong>On Order:</strong> {dataItem.UnitsOnOrder} units</p>
                <p><strong>Reorder Level:</strong> {dataItem.ReorderLevel} units</p>
                <p><strong>Discontinued:</strong> {dataItem.Discontinued}</p>
                <p><strong>Category:</strong> {dataItem.Category.CategoryName} - {dataItem.Category.Description}</p>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: products.slice(0)
    }

    expandChange = (event) => {
        event.dataItem.expanded = !event.dataItem.expanded;
        this.forceUpdate();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Grid
                data={this.state.data}
                detail={DetailComponent}
                style={{ height: '400px' }}
                expandField="expanded"
                onExpandChange={this.expandChange}
            >
                <Column field="ProductName" title="Product" width="300px" />
                <Column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="50px" />
                <Column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" width="100px" />
                <Column field="QuantityPerUnit" title="Qty Per Unit" />
            </Grid>            
        );
    }
}

class ShowAlert extends React.Component {
  showAlert() {
    alert("Im an alert");
  }

  render() {
    return <a className='k-link' onClick={this.showAlert}>+/-</a>;
  }
}

export default ShowAlert;

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.querySelector('my-app')
);

const heirarchyElement = document.getElementsByClassName("k-hierarchy-cell")[0];
ReactDOM.render(<ShowAlert />, heirarchyElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Marissa